# Mapping Commands in Python Dictionary Based Around Default Parameters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary

I'm looking to be able to use a specific system call depending on which key is accessed in a dictionary. 
Function might look like:

```
def query_ec2(self, region=None, instanceId=None):

    if region == None and instanceId == None:
        return json.loads(subprocess.check_output("aws ec2 describe-instances", shell=True))

    elif region != None and instanceId == None:
        return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(("aws ec2 describe-instances --region {}").format(region), shell=True))

    elif instanceId != None and region == None:
        return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(("aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id {}").format(instanceId), shell=True))

    else:
        return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(("aws ec2 describe-instances --region {}--instance-id {}").format(region, instanceId), shell=True))
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to get rid of conditionals here and use a standard dictionary to map the specific system calls to the supplied parameters.

Comment: To be frank, this code is very clean & readable as is. I wouldn't try to do anything fancy for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```py
import shlex


def query_ec2(self, region=None, instanceId=None):
    args = ["aws ec2 describe-instances"]
    if region:
        args.append("--region {}".format(shlex.quote(region)))
    if instanceId:
        args.append("--instance-id {}".format(shlex.quote(instanceId)))

    command = " ".join(args)
    return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True))
```

might be the cleanest way to put this.

I took the liberty of adding `shlex.quote()` calls to guard you against malicious user input.

Answer (score 0):

While @DroidX86 is right in her/his comment, you can use nested if statements. This isn't really an improvement but more a question of preference:

```
def query_ec2(self, region=None, instanceId=None):

    if region is None:
        if instanceId is None:
            return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(
                              "aws ec2 describe-instances", shell=True))
        else:
            return json.loads(subprocess.check_output((
                              "aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id \
                              {}").format(instanceId), shell=True))
    else:
        if instanceId is None:
            return json.loads(subprocess.check_output((
                              "aws ec2 describe-instances --region \
                              {}").format(region), shell=True))
        else:
            return json.loads(subprocess.check_output((
                              "aws ec2 describe-instances --region \
                              {}--instance-id {}").format(region, instanceId),
                              shell=True))
```